# Serializing custom bag object to json string int to Bool in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, json, serialization, swift

In my project, there is a bag object which was declared as static and when a customer click the "approve order" button, I serialize the bag object to JSON String. There is no problem so far. However, when I print the serialized json string, all of the "IDs" with **Int** in the bag converted to **Bool** type in json string result.

The related code blocks for this process as below:

This is my **"Serialize"** class:

```
public class Serializable : NSObject
{

func toDictionary() -> NSDictionary
{
    var aClass : AnyClass? = self.dynamicType
    var propertiesCount : CUnsignedInt = 0
    var propertiesInAClass : UnsafeMutablePointer<objc_property_t> = class_copyPropertyList(aClass, &propertiesCount)
    var propertiesDictionary : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()

    for(var i = 0; i < Int(propertiesCount); i++)
    {
        var property = propertiesInAClass[i]
        var propName = NSString(CString: property_getName(property), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        var propType = property_getAttributes(property)
        var propValue : AnyObject! = self.valueForKey(propName!)

        if(propValue is Serializable)
        {
            propertiesDictionary.setValue((propValue as Serializable).toDictionary(), forKey: propName!)
        }
        else if(propValue is Array<Serializable>)
        {
            var subArray = Array<NSDictionary>()
            for item in (propValue as Array<Serializable>)
            {
                subArray.append(item.toDictionary())
            }
            propertiesDictionary.setValue(subArray, forKey: propName!)
        }
        else if(propValue is NSData)
        {
            propertiesDictionary.setValue((propValue as NSData).base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil), forKey: propName!)
        }
        else if(propValue is Bool)
        {
            propertiesDictionary.setValue((propValue as Bool).boolValue, forKey: propName!)
        }
        else if(propValue is NSDate)
        {
            var date = propValue as NSDate
            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "Z"
            var dateString = NSString(format: "/Date(%.0f000%@)/", date.timeIntervalSince1970, dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date))
            propertiesDictionary.setValue(dateString, forKey: propName!)
        }
        else
        {
            propertiesDictionary.setValue(propValue, forKey: propName!)
        }
    }

    return propertiesDictionary
}

    func toJson() -> NSData!
    {
        var dictionary = self.toDictionary()
        var err: NSError?
        return NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictionary, options:NSJSONWritingOptions(0), error: &err)
    }

    func toJsonString() -> NSString!
    {
        return NSString(data: self.toJson(), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }

    override init()
    {

    }
}
```

This is my **BagItem** class:

```
class BagItem: Serializable, Hashable {

var uniqueID: Int = 0
override var hashValue: Int { return uniqueID.hashValue }
var bagItemId: String
var item: Item
var boughtDate: NSDate!
var boughtTime: String
var branch: Branch
var isMainItem: Bool

    override init()
    {
        self.bagItemId   = ""
        self.item        = Item()
        self.boughtDate  = NSDate()
        self.boughtTime  = ""
        self.branch      = Branch()
        self.isMainItem  = false
    }
}

func ==(lhs: BagItem, rhs: BagItem) -> Bool
{
    return lhs.uniqueID == rhs.uniqueID
}
```

This is my **"SerializationBag"** class:

```
class SerializableBag: Serializable
{
    var bag: Array<BagItem> = []

    override init()
    {

    }
}
```

This is my **"ConvertBagToJSON"** method in Bag class:

```
static func ConvertBagToJson() -> NSString
{
    var serializer: SerializableBag = SerializableBag()
    serializer.bag = self.bag
    return serializer.toJsonString()
}
```

And my returned **JSON String result** as below:

```
{
"bag": [
    {
        "branch": {
            "city": {
                "cityId": false,
                "cityName": ""
            },
            "town": {
                "townName": "",
                "townId": false
            },
            "branchName": "Branch",
            "branchId": true,
            "business": {
                "businessPhotoPath": "",
                "businessName": "",
                "businessId": true
            },
            "branchAddress": "Some Address",
            "branchTelephone": ""
        },
        "uniqueID": false,
        "boughtDate": "/Date(1414581909000+0200)/",
        "item": {
            "itemName": "Pencil",
            "itemId": true,
            "itemPrice": true
        },
        "isMainItem": true,
        "bagItemId": "9674D47B-0D2F-46CC-BA16-754875AE277D",
        "hashValue": false,
        "boughtTime": "00:30"
    }
]
}
```

As you see, in JSON String, IDs are **Bool**, but they have to be in **Int** type. How can I solve this problem ?

Thank you for your answers

Best regards

Comment: It is very interesting. There is not any other solution to do this ? @rintaro

Comment: Sorry, but I deleted the comment. I will write the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `Int` is bridged to `NSNumber` and `NSNumber` is always `is Bool`.

In your case, you don't need these lines:

```
    else if(propValue is Bool)
    {
        propertiesDictionary.setValue((propValue as Bool).boolValue, forKey: propName!)
    }
```

You can just delete them, because `NSJSONSerialization` can handle it.

```
let flg:NSNumber = true
let id:NSNumber = 1

let dict:NSDictionary = [
    "bool": flg,
    "id": id
]

let jsonDat = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: .allZeros, error: nil)!
let jsonStr = NSString(data: dat, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
// -> {"id":1,"bool":true}
```

more relevant example:

```
class Foo:NSObject {
    var flg:Bool = true
    var id:Int = 1
}

let obj = Foo()
let dict:NSDictionary = [
    "flg": obj.valueForKey("flg")!,
    "id": obj.valueForKey("id")!
]

let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: .allZeros, error: nil)!
let jsonStr = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
// -> {"flg":true,"id":1}
```

Comment: It is working, thank you so much. Plz help on fixing Double and Float values in same process